# Error while trying to share an interface across different files in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm making a card game in Typescript. So far, I have a main `app.ts` file, and these two files.

**Card.ts**

```
module Cardgame
{
    export interface Card
    {
        name: string;
    }
}
```

**Deck.ts**

```
/// <reference path='Card.ts' />

module Cardgame
{
    export interface Deck
    {
        name: string;
        content: Card[];
    }
}
```

Compiling the app, or compiling `Deck.ts` directly, yields the following error:

```
C:\Dropbox\Cardgame\app\cardgame\Deck.ts(8,12): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Card'.
```

However, placing the `Card` interface in the same file as `Deck` works fine:

```
module Cardgame
{
    export interface Card
    {
        name: string;
    }

    export interface Deck
    {
        name: string;
        content: Card[];
    }
}
```

What can I do to keep them in separate files?

Comment: The separate files should actually work fine. How are you compiling your files?

Answer (score 1):

Probably an old version of the compiler or some other error. It compiles fine as shown below : 
[image]

PS: in node you shouldn't use internal modules. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Your video was very helpful. I refactored the code into external modules and I'm no longer getting the error above. (I'm actually getting a different error due to apparently not being able to use Card[] as a data type, but that's another matter entirely)

Comment: Also, I'm using the latest (1.0.1.0) compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your references in the app.ts file.

```
/// <reference path='Card.ts' />
/// <reference path='Deck.ts' />

class App{

}
```

Then run tsc against only app.ts

tsc --out app.js app.ts

Comment: I just tried it. It still throws that compilation error on Deck.ts.